# Poptrox gallery

Tags: html, jquery

I am still a coding-newbie so any and all help is greatly appreciated.  I've been playing around with an HTML5up template(Strata), and it has a poptrox popup gallery.  I can't figure out how to  get the right images to display for each popup. Right now if you click on the pop up it allows the user to scroll through ALL the images.  I want each popup to display a different gallery of images.  Right now I have two separate galleries and have called two separate gallery functions in jquery, but when you click on a popup it displays all the images not those specific to the gallery.  I have been working on this for days, lots of googling, and can't seem to see what I am missing. Again, I would love any suggestions or advice on how to get this to work.    Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
      <section id="two">
          <h2>Menu</h2>
             <div class="row">
                 <article class="col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item ">
                     <div id="gallery1">
                        <a href="images/img/breakfast-lunch-1.png" alt="breakfast and 
                      lunch 1" class= "image fit thumb"> <img src = "images/img/crab- 
                      sandwich.png"></a>
                        <a href = "images/img/breakfast-lunch-2.png" alt 
                        ="breakfast and lunch 2" class = "image fit thumb"></a>
                     </div>
                    <h3>Breakfast &amp Lunch</h3>
                   </article>

                        
                    
           <article class="col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item">
              <div id = "gallery2">
                 <a href="images/img/dinner-1.png" class="image fit thumb nav-next 
                 nav-previous"><img src="images/img/clam-chowder.jpg" alt="clam 
                 -chowder" /></a>
                <a href = "images/img/dinner-2.png" class="image fit thumb nav-next 
                 nav-previous"></a>
               </div>
              <h3>Dinner</h3>
            </article>
          </section>
```

This is what I added to the bottom of the jquery poptrox.min.js file

```
       var foo1 = $('#gallery1');
       foo.poptrox();
       var foo2 = $('#gallery2');
       foo.poptrox();
```

Comment: why you are using foo? isn't it should be foo1 and foo2?

Comment: I haven't used jquery before.  I read  several articles on poptrox and the plugin documentation and I believe that is how it is supposed to work. However, someone on another thread just pointed out that this plug-in is  old and no longer maintained so I might just switch to another.

Comment: you have selected gallery1 and gallery2 in foo1 and foo2 variable. so this should be  var foo1 = $('#gallery1');
       foo1.poptrox();
       var foo2 = $('#gallery2');
       foo2.poptrox();

Comment: Thanks.  It still is not working.  I think I might try a different type of gallery.